# How to go back from one to another Navigation activity on back button pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation

i am making an android application in which i am using two activities one is navigation activity and other is blank activity. i have applied intent class from navigation activity to blank activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

that is working fine. Now i have to go back to the navigation activity on back button pressed in secondActivity. How I can do this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

i have used this approach but nothing done. sencond activity not go to a previous one and i have also used fragments in secondActivity

Comment: So what happens if you press back button, does it stay on the same page or the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```